# Sys::Syslog fails with invalid log level/ facility 0 when using LOG_EMERG

Tags: perl, syslog

The code below is failing for `LOG_EMERG`. If I use any other level eg. `LOG_ALERT` this works without problems. [Syslog](http://p3rl.org/Sys%3a%3aSyslog) documentation implies that this should work.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

require Sys::Syslog;
use Sys::Syslog qw(:standard :macros);
eval{Sys::Syslog::openlog('NAME', 'ndelay', 'local0')};
Sys::Syslog::syslog(Sys::Syslog::LOG_EMERG,"Message")
```

Comment: why do you `require Sys::Syslog;` and then `use Sys::Syslog`? `use Sys::Syslog qw(:standard :macros);` is equivalent to `BEGIN{ require Sys::Syslog; Sys::Syslog->import(qw(:standard :macros)); }`

Comment: Thnks.It is giving me an error if I do not explicitly import the macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a version issue:  Latest version is currently at 0.29.

to see what version your using try:

```
perl -e "use Sys::Syslog; print $Sys::Syslog::VERSION;"
```

Comment: Thanks. This is not printing anything on the system that I have. I am on perl 5.8.8. Due to various restrictions, cannot upgrade